# Could not convert string to float: '2.648.142' (Panda)

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to convert a single column, taken from an html import, from string into float.
The column(Price) includes a currency sign, that i tried to replace with ''.

```
import pandas as pd

Cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [2.648.142€,2500000€,2700000€,35000€]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])


df['Price']=df['Price'].replace('€','', regex=True)

df['Price']= df['Price'].astype(float)

print (df)
```

error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.648.142'

If i use

```
pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')
```

error:

> TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

The output only includes price < 1.000.000, therefore i assume that the double dot creates the problem.

Comment: What is 2.648.142 supposed to mean? I cannot convert it to float myself.

Comment: Maybe you just nneed to replace `.` with empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also replace `.` to empty string, because special regex character is escaped by `\`:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].replace('[€\.]','', regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
            Brand      Price
0     Honda Civic  2648142.0
1  Toyota Corolla  2500000.0
2      Ford Focus  2700000.0
3         Audi A4    35000.0
```

Comment: How did you understand that the `.` are supposed to be removed (or treated as commas at least)? Just by similarity to the other values?

Comment: @kabanus - ya, exactly.

Comment: @kabanus - and also because `The output only includes price < 1.000.000,`